# Remove [imgcaption] tags from string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, string

for example, this is a string containing the [imgcaption] tags. I would like to know if there's a way to use regex or some replacement method to remove all the [imgcaption] tags in this string? I only want the remaining mandarin characters.

```
[imgcaption imgsrc="foo.jpg" imgwidth="800" imgheight="533"]林女。[/imgcaption](香)由黄生、林嘉廖启智等合演的电影《死因无可疑》，将于本月25日上映。林修边幅兼身形人，并有个凸出的腩。
```

Hence, i would like to expect it to return a string like this, after regex:

```
林女。(香)由黄生、林嘉廖启智等合演的电影《死因无可疑》，将于本月25日上映。林修边幅兼身形人，并有个凸出的腩。
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `\[\/?imgcaption.*?\]`

```js
const text = '[imgcaption imgsrc="foo.jpg" imgwidth="800" imgheight="533"]林女。[/imgcaption](香)由黄生、林嘉廖启智等合演的电影《死因无可疑》，将于本月25日上映。林修边幅兼身形人，并有个凸出的腩。';

const regex = /\[\/?imgcaption.*?\]/g;

const result = text.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result);
```

In PHP:

```php
$text = '[imgcaption imgsrc="foo.jpg" imgwidth="800" imgheight="533"]林女。[/imgcaption](香)由黄生、林嘉廖启智等合演的电影《死因无可疑》，将于本月25日上映。林修边幅兼身形人，并有个凸出的腩。';
$result = preg_replace('/\[\/?imgcaption.*?\]/', '', $text);
echo $result;
```

Comment: thanks for this, would it work if it has imgcaption at any place in the string?

Comment: @MichelleLer It should, give it a try.